# How to push to git without merge files

Tags: git

When I push my rails app to git I have this

```
To github.com:name/name.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:name/name.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And then after git pull add some old files and photos that I deleted earlier and do not want them ..

When I run git merge my files are deleted, including photos of assets, I dont want this
Please heplp me, 
I'm new to Git and I can not deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

First add and commit your work to your local repository.

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "Some comment"
```

Then fetch the upstream updates

```
git fetch
```

Then re-base your work on top of the remote HEAD.

```
git rebase
```

This is better then merging in 90% of scenarios and leaves you with a much cleaner git history.

Provided nobody else has made any changes before you push, your push will now succeed.

```
git push
```

For more information on re-basing see: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

The above article finishes up nicely with the following

> In general the way to get the best of both worlds is to rebase local changes you’ve made but haven’t shared yet before you push them in order to clean up your story, but never rebase anything you’ve pushed somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, please don't forget to flag this question as answered then.